# SSL WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER _ssl.c:1124

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

Hello I am writing some python code with the intention of opening a ssl port which can be accessed from IPv4 as well as IPv6. The issue is that as soon as the client side script connects to the server side script, server returns error SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (_ssl.c:1124). Could some please help me.

Regards, AwesomeDude091

Code:
Server Side:

```
import socket
import sys
import ssl

HOST = None
PORT = 2512
s = None
wrappedSocket = None
context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="/home/superuser/Documents/PyCharm/certificate.pem", keyfile="/home/superuser/Documents/PyCharm/key.pem")
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    try:
        s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        wrappedSocket = context.wrap_socket(s, server_side=True)
        print(wrappedSocket)
        print('First try got called')
    except OSError as msg:
        wrappedSocket = None
        print('Got called 1')
        print(msg)
        continue
    try:
        wrappedSocket.bind(sa)
        wrappedSocket.listen(1)
        print(wrappedSocket)
        print(sa)
    except OSError as msg:
        wrappedSocket.close()
        wrappedSocket = None
        print('Got called 2')
        print(msg)
        continue
    break
if wrappedSocket is None:
    print('could not open socket')
    sys.exit(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = wrappedSocket.accept()
    connStream = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_side=True)
    data = connStream.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
    conn.send(data)
```

Client Side:

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 2512
s = None
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    try:
        s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
        print(s)
        print(sa)
    except OSError as msg:
        s = None
        print('Got called 1')
        continue
    try:
        s.connect(sa)
        s.settimeout(15.0)
        print(s)
    except OSError as msg:
        s.close()
        s = None
        print('Got called 2')
        print(msg)
        continue
    break
if s is None:
    print(s)
    print('could not open socket')
    sys.exit(1)
with s:
    s.sendall(b'Hello, World!')
    data = s.recv(1024)
print('Received', repr(data))
```

P.S. If someone could tell me how to change what gets exchanged during the connection that would also be great.

Edit: Typo

Comment: why do you use secure socket on the server side and plain socket on the client side? how its supposed to work together?

Comment: I found that in some tutorial, idk? Should I maybe use pyOpenSSL instead?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#socket-creation

Comment: Could you provide this as a code example with the code above? And does it include TLS_v3?